# How can I show Interstitial AdMob add every 3 deaths in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I have this script for my Interstitial AdMob ads:

```
public class Interstitialadscript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    void Start()
    {
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";

        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitial()
    {

         RequestInterstitial();


    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        string interstitialId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";

        if (interstitial != null)
            interstitial.Destroy();
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(interstitialId);
        interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;

        interstitial.LoadAd(CreateNewRequest());
    }

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
            interstitial.Show();
    }


    private AdRequest CreateNewRequest()
    {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

What I tried was this(in a script attached to game over scene)

```
public class loadcounter : MonoBehaviour
{

public static int loadcount=0;
public Interstitialadscript script;

void Start()
{
loadcount++;
if(loadcount % 3 ==0)
   script.ShowInterstitial();
}
```

When game over screen is loaded third time, I get NullReference error as debug log.

If anyone has different idea for how and when to load interstitial ad, feel free to suggest it.

---

what I want to achieve is, how can I get it to show ads when otherscript.deathcounter == 3?

What I tried so far is, calling ShowInterstitial() function in another script which was counting deaths once the condition was filled, but the only thing I got was NullRefference errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the other script code.

Answer (score 0):

Without other script we can only guess the problem.

But my guess is your script is not static. I had the same problem too.

I fixed it with making other script static with deathCount variable.  In ad manager script, i make bool to deathCount reach the number wanted, then i put showInterstitial(); fixed my problem.

Comment: I definetly suggesting same thing make either singleton admanager or load counter. If its no problem with your content make singleton loadcounter.